# What is wrong with my re-captcha php?

Tags: php, recaptcha

I keep getting the message `"The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again.(reCAPTCHA said: incorrect-captcha-sol."`

I have submitted it to my server, fatcow, and they tell me the issue is in the php coding, and I took the code from the code on http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/php.html, so I figured that would work.

Right now, I've run out of ideas. I've tried various things, but I am not familiar with PHP.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
    require_once('recaptchalib.php');
    $publickey = "my public key"; // you got this from the signup page
    echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
?>
```

I am inserting it into my html form just before the end of my form.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you replace 'my public key' with your actual public key?

Comment: `$publickey = "my public key"; // you got this from the signup page`

Comment: No php errors yet. First things first. I need to get the captcha image on the site and the code I gave should do that. Hopefully. Lee

Answer (score 1):

First you need to go to http://www.google.com/recaptcha and sign up.

They'll give you a key you can put into the code to use their service.

Please read and understand how recaptcha works. It's only a 1-2 pages long to read.

As well, it gives instructions on HOW to use recaptcha. It's not complicated, and it's better to understand what you're using as oppose to not understanding.

Possibly similar to: [Need help with reCAPTCHA - keep getting incorrect-captcha-sol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264703/need-help-with-recaptcha-keep-getting-incorrect-captcha-sol)

Comment: Pardon me. I forgot to mention tha I have the key and I do insert it in "public key here" when I coded the form for use.

Comment: @lee frandsent `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264703/need-help-with-recaptcha-keep-getting-incorrect-captcha-sol` Do you malformed code? See link.

Answer (score 0):

The page you linked to also said that the code you gave should be in a form with the action `verify.php` and they gave the code that should be in that verification file. Do you also have that?

Comment: I have a verify.php file in the same directory as the form page.

Comment: I see that the google capcha page has the php in a form, but I thought that was just the form on the user's page. Are you saying that the captch php must be in another form on my form page? That may explain the problem.

Comment: Also, I do have the recaptchalib.php in the same directory.

Comment: I think it would not hurt to try. You should also check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264703/need-help-with-recaptcha-keep-getting-incorrect-captcha-sol, which FinalForm links to in his answer.

Comment: I checked that out before posting. His situation is different in that his whole page is php. I am inserting php in an html page. Also, I only know html, css and javascript, so when it comes to php, I am a beginner. Lee

Comment: Hi, Iam back at it again, using 1264703/, as suggested. I have a form (estimateform1.html) and a processing doc (verify.php). The recaptcha image is not showing, and upon submitting, only a blank page (ref:verify.php). Need quite a bit of help with the php, I'm sure. Here's the essentials of the estimateform1.html:

Comment: @lee I suggest that if you are having a different problem from your original question then you should ask a new question.

Comment: <form name="estimateform1" method="post" action="verify.php?id=estimate&action=submit#estimate">
<div id="table"><br>
<h2>FCS Estimate Form</h2><br>
<table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0">
<tr><td><fontcolor="red">*</font>Full Name:</td>
<td><inputtype="text" name="name" size="35"></td>
</tr>

Answer (score 0):

It's been 5 years OP, I sincerely hope you've figured out a solution.  But for others like me who still get this cryptic message, I can tell you what resolved it for me.  It turns out I was trying to implement the previous version of Google's recaptcha, [version 1.0](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/old/docs/php). When someone pointed that out to me and I ran through the instructions for [version 2.0](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display), the error message went away and the recaptcha displayed as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Make ensure that your form submit with post not get.
Ensure that your reCaptcha verified only once.
Ensure that your reCaptcha keys are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I found this online on another website.

Set your php setting allow_furl_open to yes... mine was set to no  (allow_furl_open = YES)

Setting this in my fatcow settings allowed the ReCaptcha v2 to work... FINALLY.

Now I have found my email script isn't working.... always something...

Good luck!