# Problems with recaptcha installation in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, recaptcha

I've tried implementing recaptcha in to my Codeigniter application but it's throwing an error.

I have loaded my helper:

```
$this->load->helper('recaptchalib_helper');
```

My Controller:

```
$publickey = $this->config->item('recaptchakey');
$data['recaptchakey'] = $publickey;
$return = recaptcha_check_answer($publickey, $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], $this->input->post("recaptcha_challenge_field"), $this->input->post("recaptcha_response_field"));

if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
   $this->load->view('form', $data);
} else {            
   if(!$return->is_valid) {
      echo 'failed';
      $this->load->view('form', $data);
} else {
      echo 'success';
      $this->load->view('form', $data);
}
```

The recurring error is "invalid-site-private-key" and "incorrect-captcha-sol" - can someone tell me where I am going wrong please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `invalid-site-private-key` is related to the data you entered in the configuration file. Read more here: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify

The `incorrect-captcha-sol` is related to the way your view is built. Read more: [Need help with reCAPTCHA - keep getting incorrect-captcha-sol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264703/need-help-with-recaptcha-keep-getting-incorrect-captcha-sol)