# PHP reCaptcha won't validate

Tags: php, recaptcha

I'm trying to get reCaptcha working with a form on my website and for some reason I keep getting an error that the wrong captcha was entered.  Does anyone see anything wrong with my code?

```
require_once('includes/recaptchalib.php');

$publickey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$privatekey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

if (isset($category)) {
    if ($edit == 'edit') {
    include "includes/updatelisting.php";
    } else {
    $response = recaptcha_check_answer($privatekey,
        $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
        $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
        $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

        if ($response->is_valid) {
                include "includes/insertlisting.php";
        } else {
        echo "Eh, That wasn't right. Try Again.";

        }
     }

} else {
```

Here is the code in the actual form..

```
// Display the reCaptcha form
    echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey, $error);
```

Comment: this might help https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php

Comment: why don't you add $response->error to your else to see what its error is.

Comment: found on link above. `$error -- string. optional (null is the default)  If this string is set, the reCAPTCHA area will display the error code given. This error code comes from ReCaptchaResponse->$error` You might want to try to remove $error.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue.  Apparently my  tags were inside the  tags.  Once I put the form tags outside the table tags everything worked perfectly.  Very strange.  Here is a link to the answer I found  [Need help with reCAPTCHA - keep getting incorrect-captcha-sol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264703/need-help-with-recaptcha-keep-getting-incorrect-captcha-sol)

Answer (score 0):

When you call `echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey, $error);` did you already have `$error` declared?

You might want to declare it first (and yes, make it a string with one space):

```
$error = ' ';
echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey, $error);
```

Also, check to see if `$category` really is set before trying to validate.

Comment: Yes, both of those are correct.  $error is declared and $category is set.  If there's nothing else wrong with the code then I can only suspect that the public or private keys are not working for some reason.

Comment: @Budove Everything else is looking good, and the syntax for handling the response is right. Not sure what the issue could be. Have you tried doing a `print_r($response)` to look at the object itself?

Comment: print_r($response) output is ReCaptchaResponse Object ( [is_valid] => [error] => incorrect-captcha-sol )

Comment: what about print_r($_POST) is recaptcha_challenge_field/recaptcha_response_field being sent? otherwise you might want to check if your private/public keys are correct.

Comment: Class - Neither of those are being sent apparently, they weren't included in the array.

Comment: make sure that the echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey, $error); is within the form eg: <form...>...<?php echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey, $error); ?>...</form>

Comment: I found the error once I realized those fields weren't being sent.  VERY strange issue.  My form tags were inside the table, once I placed them outside the table tags everything worked perfectly.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264703/need-help-with-recaptcha-keep-getting-incorrect-captcha-sol